# Change state of button during a period

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript

I want to disable and change my class button after click during a period,
What is the best way.

Today I used this, but I not very satisfied

```
startJob(jobName: String): void {
    this.inverseStartButtonState();

    setTimeout(() => {
       this.inverseStartButtonState();
    }, 5000);

    Launch job ....

}

inverseStartButtonState() {
    this.enableStartJob = !this.enableStartJob;
}
```

Can I do this in one line, with setTimout or any thing else ?
Or is there a bootstrap (or others) class which do this ? Thanks

Comment: Can you use Angular animation? https://angular.io/guide/animations#delay

Comment: I will see that (so duration instead of delay I think)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
function inverseStartButtonState(enabled, amountOfTime) {

    this.enableStartJob = !this.enableStartJob;

    if ( !enabled )
    {
        setTimeout(() => {this.inverseStartButtonState(!enabled); }, amountOfTime);
    }
}
```